# Problem 25 (e), A first course in algebraic topology, Kosniowski.

Tags: algebraic-topology

**Problem 25 (e) [A first course in algebraic topology, Kosniowski]** Let $D_1,\, D_2$ are 2-discs with boundary circles $S_1,\, S_2$ respectively. The space $X$ is the union of $D_1$ and $D_2$ with points in $S_1$ identified to points in $S_2$ by the rule $\exp(2\pi i t)\in S_1$ is identified with $\exp(2\pi i n t)$ in $S_2$ where $n$ is some fixed positive integer. Prove that $X$ is simply connected.

Hi. I am trying to prove problem 25 (e) of the book Algebraic Topology by the author Kosniowski by means of the theorem of seifert van kampen. How could I start showing it?

Comment: You could start by stating the  Seifert-van Kampen theorem. It might help you figure out how to apply it to your problem.

Comment: Well, I have the following starting point but I don't know if it will be okay. (trying to follow the reasoning from the previous example book).
without losing generality, let $D_1$ and $D_2$ unit balls.
Let $U_1=X-(1,0)$ and $U_2=X-(-1,0)$ and $U_1\cap U_2$ open sets in $X$ and path connected. Now, I need compute the fundamental group of $U_1,U_2$ and $U_1\cap U_2$....

Comment: @eraldcoil I'm not sure but it seems that you removed points on the boundary of those disks to form an open cover. I feel like this is not the most obvious solution. The two components of $X$ are already given, so why not take sufficiently small open nhbd around $D_1$ and $D_2$. Moreover, notice that $S_2$ winds $S_1$ $n$ times by identification, meaning that $D_2$, under the attachment, admits the structure of an $n$-fold dunce cap, whose fundamental group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/n$.

Comment: @eraldcoil And after that, Seifert Van Kampen tells us that because ther is a disk attached at the other side, the generator of the dunce cap is null-homotopic, so the fundamental group of $X$ is should be trivial. (This is just an intuitive approach. A proof has to show each step in detail...)